# Why is the friction vector resolved even though the inclined plane is the reference plane?

Tags: friction

[image: An image from college website]

I do not understand why the frictional force is resolved even though it is already on the reference x-axis. Asked this question to college teacher and got reply,"I will do it later" and later never came. Still, why is it that way? Why has been frictional force resolved with a cos?

Comment: because the normal force is $W cos \alpha $ (the weight is not perpendicular to the surface)

Comment: @brucesmitherson, But frictional force depends on normal force and not the weight.

Comment: do you know how to calculate the normal force?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The Frictional force is: $$Wcos\alpha\mu$$
Because N, the normal force is:
$$N = Wcos\alpha$$